# Sorting Arraylist by an object variable

Tags: sorting, arraylist

Any ideas on how to apply Collections.sort method to sort my arraylist by priority of each grocItem object within the itemData ArrayList?

```
public class GroceryProgram {

    private final static int GROC_SIZE = 6;
    private final List<ItemData> itemData = new ArrayList<ItemData>();

    private void setUpList() {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < GROC_SIZE; i++)  {

           System.out.print("\nEnter item name (" + i + ") : ");               
           String name = keyboard.next();

           System.out.print("\nEnter the price of item (" + i + ") : ");
           double cost = keyboard.nextDouble();

           System.out.print("\nEnter Priority Number (" + i + ") : ");
           int priority = keyboard.nextInt();

           ItemData grocItem = new ItemData(name, cost, priority);
           itemData.add(grocItem); // add grocery items to itemData ArrayList

           Collections.sort(grocItem);
           for (Int priority : priority) {
               System.out.println(integer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `sort()` with a Comparator. For example, a Comparator in ascending-order of priority could look like this.

```
Collections.sort( items, new Comparator<ItemData>() {
    public int compare (ItemData o1, ItemData o2) {
        int comp = o1.getPriority() - o2.getPriority();
        return comp;
    }
});
```

PS: 'itemData' is bad variable naming -- it would refer to a single item, not a list. 'groceryItems', 'stockItems' or 'itemList' would be better.

**Variable names should enable you to speak in meaningful, clear, concise English about your software.**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use [Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to deal with this? You could simply do the following :

```
Collections.sort(itemData, new Comparator() {
  public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    // Return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom comparator as below:

```
Collections.sort(itemData ,new PriorityComparator());

        //print sorted arraylist,it will print the data in ascending order (low priority->high priority).feel free to modify if you want to go for descending order
        System.out.println(itemData );
```

PriorityComparator class definition:

```
private static class PriorityComparator implements Comparator{

    @Override
    public int compare(ItemData object1, ItemData object2) {
        return (object1.priority< object2.priority) ? -1: (object1.priority> object2.priority) ? 1:0 ;
    }

}
```

Reference:

[how-to-sort-arraylist-in-java-example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-sort-arraylist-in-java-example.html)

I hope it will be helpful !!